# Salesforce One, is it really a new product?

Tags: force.com

I've received yesterday tons of emails announcing [Salesforce One](http://developer.salesforce.com/platform/overview)

> Salesforce.com just launched the Salesforce1 Customer Platform, **a
>   new platform** designed to help you build apps for the Internet of
>   Customers

But I don't see in the features anything new, is it?

Comment: @mast0r Sorry for the duplicate entry. I've tried to delete it but I couldn't. I voted to remove it.

Answer (score 3):

In simple words and without the marketing fluff, you get a nice framework for developing mobile applications.

Three most important points are:

- Mobile-friendly applications can be easily created (even with configuration; "by clicking")
- Javascript APIs have been upgraded and new ones introduced
- Mobile Chatter will be replaced by a new "Salesforce1" mobile application

---

1. [Salesforce1 App Developer Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/salesforce1/salesforce1_guide.pdf)
2. [Salesforce1 Platform API Services Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/salesforce1api/salesforce1_api_guide.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

There is a new app called Salesforce1. This is an evolution of the Chatter app and has a very similar if not identical interface, i.e., ability to make standard and custom objects and automation processes available from within the salesforce org to the app, i.e., customise the app. It also enable salesforce to get away from the confusion of salesforce and salesforce.com and Chatter. As a branding exercise Chatter is heavily associated with Social Enterprise which in turn has been a failure in communicating the ability of the Salesforce platform to include social objects, interfaces and processes.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce1 is platform used to build apps for the `internet of customer`. By using Salesforce1 every company can connect with their customer,employees, `devices` and `ISVs` and all from anywhere to everywhere in a faster way.

Main thing what i study about this is its use for sales personnel who can able to connect Salesforce CRM and its updates from anywhere from mobile just by one click.

Salesforce1 is also have many apps in which i studied about the three which is `mobile apps` , `admin apps` and `Costomer apps`.

By use of `mobile apps` any one can access salesforce CRM only by one login. Developer can use action as a tool which is define by public API.

`Admin App` provide more facility to admin as they can can reset password,deactivate users, define sharing rules for users and also can see the scheduled maintenance of salesforce.com.

'Customer App' is used by costomers to save `leads` or `opportunity` they can update the opportunity and also watch the performance of company or other customers.

It provide much more access for venders on App Exchange and also it provide 10 times more API's then salesforce.

`Heroku`,`.net`, `salesforce` and all other web apps can use the salesforce1 platform.

overall we can say that its more faster and Social next generation platform and app who provide more connection and functionality in a faster way.